# How to validate the file type of a file uploaded by the user in a Shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, shiny-server

I'm trying to create a Shiny App (using R Studio).

I want to use a fileInput widget (named ffile) to read an xlsx or xls file from the user. However, I need it to make sure that it's the correct file type, otherwise the rest of the code will not work. I read about the validate() and need() functions. So I did it like this:

```
data<-reactive({ 
infile = input$ffile 
if (is.null(infile)) 
return(NULL)
ext<-c('application/vnd.ms-excel','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')

o<-is.element(infile$type,ext)
validate(need(o,'Wrong ext. Select .xls, .xlsx or .csv'))
file<-read.xlsx(infile$datapath, 1)
return(file) })
```

I tried loading a .docx document and it was successfully blocked and the warning message was displayed as desired. However, when I try to load a correct .xlsx file it would still show the warning message instead of actually accepting it. I do not know if I'm using the validate/need incorrectly or there is something about MIMEs that I don't quite understand. Help would be appreaciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the accepted MIME directly in the `fileInput` object in your `ui.R` using the `accept` argument:

```
fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
                accept=c('application/vnd.ms-excel',
                         'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
                         '.xls',
                         '.xlsx'))
```

This will only let the user select excel files from the file browser window that opens.

In your `server.R`, you can then just get the data from the file without validating.

Comment: I tried that, my code for the widget in `ui.R` looks like this:

` fileInput("ffile", label = h4("Choose file"),  accept=c('application/vnd.ms-excel','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet','.xls',  '.xlsx'))`

but when I run it it completely ignores the `accept` argument. It still lets me choose any type of file by default.

Comment: This will only work in a web browser, but not in the Rstudio viewer.

Comment: I have verified wikiselev's comment, it works perfectly in the web browser.

Comment: No, it does not work if you drag and drop the file